# Why fly to JFK instead of EWR?

Tags: new-york-city, jfk, ewr

As an ignorant person visiting Manhattan, why would I choose to fly to JFK if EWR is significantly cheaper?

The distance is roughly the same at 19 miles, and the driving time is about 20 minutes more (40 minutes vs an hour), probably because of the tolls.

In my case, it’s $545 round-trip to JFK. On the other hand, if I fly to EWR and then leave from JFK, the ticket is $320.

Also, I’d be taking a taxi or an uber.

Comment: Beware that taxis to/from EWR are stupidly expensive (easily $100+) because of state restrictions on where cabbies can operate. Uber is cheaper though.

Comment: Taxi trips between JFK and Manhattan benefit from a flat rate (between $52.80 and $60.30 depending on time and exact destination in Manhattan), while trips to/from LGA or EWR use standard metered fares + a lot of extras.

Comment: JFK is also linked to two metro lines. But your assumption is wrong. EWR may be sometime cheaper, but it doesn't offer all flights (and connections) of JFK (or maybe not the better time to flight). So, there are too many reasons, and I think the answer would tend to be opinion based (my case is different to every other cases)

Answer (score 3):

A taxi from EWR to Manhattan may be slightly more expensive than from JFK because the taxi crosses jurisdictions -- you would be taking a Newark or Elizabeth taxi which would charge additional fare in New York. However, the difference would not be enough to offset the difference in fare you are looking at, and in general JFK and EWR are considered about equally good for access to Manhattan.

Comment: If you do want a private car ride from EWR into Manhattan, you might also consider a car service like [Dial 7](https://www.dial7.com/) or [Carmel](https://www.carmellimo.com/) (with either service, google around for a coupon), which will be broadly similar to Uber but offers a fixed price. The base fare should be on the order of $50-$60, but remember you're on the hook for around $20 worth of tolls, plus a tip.

Comment: You would normally take Uber though?

Comment: @JonathanReez Uber's price estimation tool shows nothing under $100 right now.  There's not much point.